# Why does passing an expression object to where returns a different result than typing the lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have the following code which returns a list of six objects correctly

```
var items = db.items.take(100);
 var result = items.Where(m => m.Cost.ToString().ToLower().Contains("67.5")).ToList(); //returns 6 items
```

I'm trying to do the same thing using dynamic expressions.

```
// Print out the expression.
// .ToString() returns "m => m.Cost.ToString().ToLower().Contains("67.5")"
var whereClause = ContainsPredicate<item>("Cost", "67.5"); 
var result = items.Where(whereClause).ToList(); //returns 0 items
```

When I tries to use sql profiler to see what was being sent to the DB I noticed that it removes my clause and adds `WHERE 0 = 1`

ContainsPredicate method implementation :

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ContainsPredicate<T>(string memberName, string searchValue)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
            var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, memberName);

            MethodCallExpression memberToString = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(member), member.GetType().GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes));

            MethodCallExpression memberToLower = Expression.Call(memberToString,"ToLower", null);

            var body = Expression.Call(memberToLower,"Contains",Type.EmptyTypes,Expression.Constant(searchValue));

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        }
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you try with just `Func<T, bool>` an expression has to be compiled first etc

Comment: What is the datatype of `m.Cost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void Test()
{
    var myItem = new Item() { Cost = 67.5 };
    var items = new List<Item> { myItem };

    var result = items.Where(m => 
    m.Cost.ToString().ToLower().
    Contains("67,5")).ToList();

    var whereClause = ContainsPredicate<Item>("Cost", "67,5");

    // var test1 = whereClause(myItem);
    var result2 = items.Where(whereClause).ToList(); // returns 1 result in my case
}

public static Func<T, bool> ContainsPredicate<T>(string memberName, string searchValue)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
    var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, memberName);

    // Mistake was here:
    var doubleToStr = member.Type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
    MethodCallExpression memberToString = Expression.Call(member, doubleToStr);

    MethodCallExpression memberToLower = 
        Expression.Call(memberToString, "ToLower", null);

    var body = Expression.Call(memberToLower, "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes
        , Expression.Constant(searchValue));

    var lamb = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

    // we need to compile
    return lamb.Compile();
}
```

First thing i did was only compile `memberToLower` and that returned the string "m.cost" instead of your double. "m.cost" will obviously never contain "67.5". So there you go.

Are you sure you don't want something like this:

```
public static Func<T, bool> ContainsPredicate2<T>(string memberName, string searchValue)
{
    var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(memberName);

    Func<T, bool> func = (T obj2) =>
        prop.GetValue(obj2).ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue);

    return func;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it.
```// Mistake was here:
 var doubleToStr = member.Type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
 MethodCallExpression memberToString =Expression.Call(member,doubleToStr);```
I didn't want to compile the expression at the end because I'm going to append to it , for example :
```var whereClause = ContainsPredicate<Item>("Cost", "67,5");
whereClause = whereClause.Or(ContainsPredicate<Item>("Name", "TestString"));```
it's working now

Comment: I used 
```member.GetType().GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes)```
instead of
```member.Type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes)```